# Buying close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, voting-limits

Ever since having stepped over the 3k reputation limit required to participate in casting close votes I actively "enjoyed" that privilege. Lately, however, I seem to quickly cap the daily vote limit and wander around the site, actually looking for answerable questions and helplessly getting stuck eyeing questions that should be closed or belong to superuser/serverfault/younameit.

Would it be superfluous to post a feature request to buy votes off your own reputation? Much like starting a bounty, I'd not hesitate in sacrificing, say 200 rep, for another +X votes for the day.

Any thoughts?

---

**EDIT:** Question rephrased.

*Aside from my awareness that there's always the apply-for-moderator-option, I'd like to point out that this is not a cry for support of a self-obsessed individual (as suggested by a deleted answer). While browsing for actually answerable (as per individual profession) questions during the day, you'll encounter stuff that needs moving to an appropriate SE section. For that, close votes are fast depleted. That's what the question was about.*

Comment: *opens overcoat* Can I interest you in a close vote, kind sir?  I have a fine selection of new close votes, and for the discriminating moderator a rare collection of close votes preserved from the early, contentious days of stack overflow.  With these low prices, they are sure to be gone soon!

Comment: @Polly I'll have two close votes from the Beta phase. How much would those be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limit is to ensure that

- no single user places an undue influence on what types of questions are closed
- people are careful in their choice of closing questions
- many people participate in the process, rather than just a few

If you really believe you need more moderation power then apply for a moderator position next time site elections come around.

A better option is to participate in the chat rooms and post questions that you find which need additional close votes.  The chat room [Regulator Headquarters](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/regulator-headquarters) appears to be a good choice for this.

Comment: Thanks, @Pollyanna. I didn't know about Regulator HQ.

Comment: Rather than asking in chat - wouldn't it be better to flag for mod attention?

Comment: @Barry: if it needs to be closed *quickly* for some reason, yes. If it needs additional moderator work (merging, for instance), yes. If you're on a small SE site without a large and healthy population of users with the ability to close, *definitely*! Otherwise, no - leverage the time and abilities of the rest of the community rather than dumping more work onto the moderators.